# Jetty fails to deploy war file

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jetty

I'm trying to deploy a simple JSF "hello world" application to Jetty 9.3.11 and get the following error:

```
2016-09-17 21:05:45.660:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-1: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@b3fe46b{/JSFProject_war,jar:file:///E:/12345/JSFProject/out/artifacts/JSFProject_war/JSFProject_war.war!/,null}{E:\12345\JSFProject\out\artifacts\JSFProject_war\JSFProject_war.war}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces-2.2.1.jar!/ not found in E:\12345\JSFProject\out\artifacts\JSFProject_war\JSFProject_war.war
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:142)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.getTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanForTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanJars(MetaInfConfiguration.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

war file contains path WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces-2.2.1.jar 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Go to Project Settings->Artifacts, and see if you add this JAR to your artifact. My guess is you don't.

Comment: Looks like some Intellij Idea issue. I copied the war file to jetty/webapp folder and started server - everything went normal. If I deploy artifact within Idea then I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Changing the artifact in `Project Structure` `Project Settings` `Artifacts` from `Web Application: Archive` to `Web Application: Exploded` solved the issue somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `javax.faces-2.2.1.jar` in your WAR artifact.
You don't have any errors in project options?

Comment: It is in my WAR artifact. No, I don't have any errors in project options. Like I said before the error appears only if I deploy artifact to jetty within IDE (Intellij Idea).